Automate PowerBI tables export process
I'm trying to automate a process I need to execute every month: export 5 tables for two different months (so applying filters 10 times, exporting tables everytime I need to change filters).
It takes 10min, but the reality is: I need to do and I don't want.
I'd like to integrate this in our ADF pipeline.
Is this possible?
I was thinking something like getting data from PBI, apply all needed filters and at the export that into the datalake storage.
Difficulty here is on how to get data.
I saw there's an API for it, but I'm not sure on how to work with it, neither which kind of API I really need.
